# mysql cluster the table is full, workaround?

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing, partitioning

We are trying to put several Tb in to MySQL Cluster, unfortunately the index does not fit in to memory.

Are there way to overcome this limitations of mysql?

are there way in mysql process range operations in parallel?

My data has a 3D points: (id x y z idkey someblob) inside the MYisam with 128 partitions. The NDBCLuster was unable load the data due to memory limits.

indexing goes over idkey(this is pre calculated peano-hilbert key).The total row count is about 10^9.

Thanks Arman.

**EDIT**
my setup is 2 datanodes 2 mysqld one mdm.
8Gb RAM per ndb with 4 cores.

The whole system has 30Tb Raid6.
The system is linux Scientific LInux 6.0, the cluster is 7.1 compiled from source.

Comment: OS / Hardware setup? Error messages you get - it'd be useful if you provided those.

Comment: The error message is in the title: "The table 'foo' is full".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like MySQL is ill-suited for the task (sorry). I would check out Tokyo Tyrant, maybe MongoDB or any other distributed key-value storage system. There are also specialized commercial products.

MongoDB is [able to swap out some of it's indexes to the HD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811299/mongodb-index-ram-relationship). I guess your problem is that MySQL just can't do that (I'm not a MySQL-guy though).

Comment: Yes probably we hit the mysql limits. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to modify your config.ini file.

```
DataMemory=15000M
IndexMemory=2560M
```

But if two values are too high, you will encounter this bug:
Unable to use due to bitmap pages missaligned!!

So I'm still trying to solve it. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when I was loading only DB tables' structure. Which means `DataMemory` or `IndexMemory` were not of help here.
Also the number of tables didn't reach the limit in `MaxNoOfTables` so it is not the issue as well.
The solution for me here was to increase the values for `MaxNoOfOrderedIndexes` and `MaxNoOfUniqueHashIndexes` which reflect the max number of indexes you can have in the cluster. So if there are many indexes in your DB try to increase those variables accordingly.
Of course, a [rolling restart](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-cluster-rolling-restart.html) must be done after that change to take effect!