# Is there a way to force mongodb to store certain index in ram?

Tags: mongodb, caching, indexing, ram, nosql

I have a collection with a relatively big index (but less than ram available)  and looking at performance of find on this collection and amount of free ram in my system given by htop it's seems that mongo is not storing full index in the ram. Is there a way to force mongo to store this particular index in the ram?

Example query:

```
> db.barrels.find({"tags":{"$all": ["avi"]}}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor tags_1",
        "nscanned" : 300393,
        "nscannedObjects" : 300393,
        "n" : 300393,
        "millis" : 55299,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "tags" : [
                        [
                                "avi",
                                "avi"
                        ]
                ]
        }
}
```

Not the all objects are tagged with "avi" tag:

```
> db.barrels.find().explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
        "nscanned" : 823299,
        "nscannedObjects" : 823299,
        "n" : 823299,
        "millis" : 46270,
        "indexBounds" : {

        }
}
```

Without "$all":

```
db.barrels.find({"tags": ["avi"]}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor tags_1 multi",
        "nscanned" : 300393,
        "nscannedObjects" : 300393,
        "n" : 0,
        "millis" : 43440,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "tags" : [
                        [
                                "avi",
                                "avi"
                        ],
                        [
                                [
                                        "avi"
                                ],
                                [
                                        "avi"
                                ]
                        ]
                ]
        }
}
```

Also this happens when I search for two or more tags (it scans every item as if were no index):

```
> db.barrels.find({"tags":{"$all": ["avi","mp3"]}}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor tags_1",
        "nscanned" : 300393,
        "nscannedObjects" : 300393,
        "n" : 6427,
        "millis" : 53774,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "tags" : [
                        [
                                "avi",
                                "avi"
                        ]
                ]
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running 'explain' on your query For clues why it is slow?

Comment: @gWaldo Added example query, but looking at it I found no clues.

Comment: I'll update my answer as relating to this info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  MongoDB allows the system to manage what is stored in RAM.

With that said, you should be able to keep the index in RAM by running queries against the indexes (check out [query hinting](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Optimization#Optimization-Hint)) periodically to keep them from getting stale.

Useful References:

- [Checking Server Memory Usage](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Checking+Server+Memory+Usage)
- [Indexing Advice and FAQ](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexing+Advice+and+FAQ)

Additionally, Kristina Chodorow provides this [excellent answer regarding the relationship between MongoDB Indexes and RAM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2815095/428779)

---

**UPDATE:**

After the update providing the .explain() output, I see the following:

- The query is hitting the index.
- nscanned is the number of items (docs or index entries) examined.
- nscannedObjects is the number of docs scanned
- n is the number of docs that match the specified criteria
- your dataset is 300393 entries, which is the total number of items in the index, and the matching results.

I may be reading this wrong, but what I'm reading is that all of the items in your collection are valid results.  Without knowing your data, it would seem that every item contains the tag "avi".  The other thing that this means is that this index is almost useless; indexes provide the most value when they work to narrow the resultant field as much as possible.

From MongoDB's "[Indexing Advice and FAQ](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexing+Advice+and+FAQ#IndexingAdviceandFAQ-Understanding%7B%7Bexplain%7D%7D%27soutput.)" page:

> Understanding explain's output. There are three main fields to look
>   for when examining the explain command's output:
>
> - cursor: the value for cursor can be either BasicCursor or BtreeCursor.
>     The second of these indicates that the given query is using an index.
> - nscanned: he number of documents scanned.
> - n: the number of documents
>     returned by the query. You want the value of n to be close to the
>     value of nscanned. What you want to avoid is doing a collection scan,
>     that is, where every document in the collection is accessed. This is
>     the case when nscanned is equal to the number of documents in the
>     collection.
> - millis: the number of milliseconds require to complete the
>     query. This value is useful for comparing indexing strategies, indexed
>     vs. non-indexed queries, etc.

Comment: Oh, how sad :(
Some queries are already running as the project is under constant load but ram is not getting used, I don't know what to do. I'm not deep into this project yet, so will it be wise to change database to say, redis, to be able to store indexes in ram? Is there any workarounds (say mounting mongo index files onto some kind of RAM disk?)

Comment: If you need to keep persistent data, Redis is not the answer (though it is awesome.)  I'm curious - What makes you think that RAM is not getting used?  If your queries are hitting indexes (which you can test for), they have to go into RAM.

Comment: Yet may be load is not high enough? I have one query every ten minutes or so yet this query runs for 100-200 seconds.

Comment: You could create your indexes on RAMdisk, but I'd avoid that; you're adding complication.

Comment: These two articles don't quite address what I think you're asking, but they may give you some insight into how MongoDB and RAM relate.  http://blog.serverdensity.com/2011/01/31/mongodb-monitoring-mongostat/ and http://architects.dzone.com/articles/some-useful-tips-mongodb

Comment: I have 2gb ram total, 700 megs of it is free and this index alone size is given by totalIndexSize() is
1599341504
So if index is placed into ram I should have about 500 free megs.

Comment: I've added a couple of (hopefully) relevant and helpful links

Comment: It is actually multikey index created as described in http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Full+Text+Search+in+Mongo may this be somehow related to the problem?

Comment: Updated!  Analysis and further links

Comment: Not the all objects are tagged with avi tag, as the total number of objects is higher:
> db.barrels.count()          
823299
May be it is because mongo builds separate index for each tag? But I think you are right: in my case indexes are almost useless.

Comment: Ah.  Interesting that it takes less time to do the table scan for everything rather than the query.

Comment: what happens if you take the '$all' operator out of the query (since you're only looking for one value)?

Comment: I've included additional info into the initial post.
The problem is sometimes I need to find all items tagged by two or more tags, for example: db.barrels.find({"tags":{"$all": ["avi","mp3"]}}) and this takes even more time: 53774 milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks, for the help! I've switched to redis and (almost) everything works fine now.

Comment: Sorry that we couldn't figure this one out, but I'm happy that you found *a* solution!  Redis is pretty awesome, too!

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to force mongo to store this particular index in the ram?

Sure, you can walk the index with an index-only query. That will force MongoDB to load every block of the index. But it has to be "index-only", otherwise you will also load all of the associated documents.

The only benefit this will provide is to make some potential future queries faster if those parts of the index are required.

However, if there are parts of the index that are not being accessed by the queries already running, why change this?

Comment: The thing is I use multikey index on some kind of "tags" to allow users to search on this field later. Some queries many take up to 100 seconds which is too long, and I think it is because of bad hdd performance because there is a huge difference between ssd and hdd machines.