# Pymongo query taking endless time

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-query

Below is my indexes,

```
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "spider.pages",
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "url" : 1
        },
        "unique" : true,
        "ns" : "spider.pages",
        "name" : "url_1"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "parsed" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "spider.pages",
        "name" : "parsed_1"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "date" : 1,
            "category" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "spider.pages",
        "name" : "date_1_category_1"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "indexed" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "spider.pages",
        "name" : "indexed_1"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "link_extracted" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "spider.pages",
        "name" : "link_extracted_1"
    }
]
```

From my python command line interpreter I get the following,

```
>>> [item for item in  pages.find({u'link_extracted': 0}, { u'_id':1}).sort(u'link_extracted', 1).limit(10)]
[{u'_id': ObjectId('53f988d820ba2709e89a1dc2')}, {u'_id': ObjectId('53f988d820ba270a1a9a1dbd')}, {u'_id': ObjectId('53f988e720ba2708fe9a1de4')}, {u'_id': ObjectId('53f994b620ba2706099a231e')}, {u'_id': ObjectId('53f988d820ba270bb49a1d10')}, {u'_id': ObjectId('53f994b720ba2706099a2320')}, {u'_id': ObjectId('53f9918720ba2708fe9a1fab')}, {u'_id': ObjectId('53f9949b20ba270bb49a215a')}, {u'_id': ObjectId('53f78ee420ba27220010098d')}, {u'_id': ObjectId('53f78ee620ba2721ed79d317')}]
>>> [item for item in  pages.find({u'link_extracted': 0}, { u'_id':1}).sort(u'indexed', 1).limit(10)]
[{u'_id': ObjectId('53fb38c420ba27327b725aa9')}, {u'_id': ObjectId('53fb334d20ba2715f87265c2')}, {u'_id': ObjectId('53fb38f520ba2715f872674c')}, {u'_id': ObjectId('53fb38f520ba27327b725abe')}, {u'_id': ObjectId('53fb3eab20ba273348725c0c')}, {u'_id': ObjectId('53fafc1920ba27149b7257fa')}, {u'_id': ObjectId('53fafc1620ba27149b7257f7')}, {u'_id': ObjectId('53fafc1520ba27149b7257f6')}, {u'_id': ObjectId('53fb38f020ba2715f8726748')}, {u'_id': ObjectId('53fb38ef20ba2732d8725a9a')}]
>>> [item for item in  pages.find({u'link_extracted': 0}, { u'_id':1}).sort(u'url', 1).limit(10)]
[{u'_id': ObjectId('53f848d920ba27319c4338ef')}, {u'_id': ObjectId('53f810e120ba27222952d374')}, {u'_id': ObjectId('53f810e120ba27222952d373')}, {u'_id': ObjectId('53f80bd220ba27222d52caef')}, {u'_id': ObjectId('53f80bd220ba27222d52caf0')}, {u'_id': ObjectId('53f823c220ba27222952d922')}, {u'_id': ObjectId('53f84c7720ba2731964338ff')}, {u'_id': ObjectId('53f911f620ba27458f434158')}, {u'_id': ObjectId('53f8163c20ba27222952d4cb')}, {u'_id': ObjectId('53f8162c20ba27222952d4c1')}]
```

But when I type the following I get an endless delay!

```
>>> [item for item in  pages.find({u'link_extracted': 0}, { u'_id':1}).sort(u'date', 1).limit(10)] # Endless wait
```

I have 0.6 million of documents and each has *date* property.

Comment: Is it slow when you do the query in the Mongo console?

Comment: I waited more than 10 min, then *Ctrl + Z*'ed with frustration. It is not supposed to be slow. *date* is already on the index list.

Comment: Yeah, but `date` is on a different index than `link_extracted`. What happens if you remove the sort? What happens if you modify the `link_extracted` index to be a composite on `link_extracted` and `date`?

Comment: It works after removing sort flawlessly or using compound indexes. Please write an answer and I will accept it. Please add a brief comments with your answer about compound index and hopefully effect on memory usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that because you're using `link_extracted` in your query, it is skipping the `date` index and attempting to sort the result set based on date. This is slow when there are a large number of records.

You can solve this by using a [composite index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-compound-index/):

```
db.pages.ensureIndex({link_extracted: 1, date: 1})
```

As is always the case with indexes this will add some memory overhead, and it will add some processing overhead as the index is being created. You can see more details on MongoDB and index memory usage here: [MongoDB index/RAM relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811299/mongodb-index-ram-relationship)